# swagger spec response multiple array

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

my swagger.yaml is here

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: An array of Students
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Students'
definitions:
  Students:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Student'
  Student:
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
```

but, result is

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLflQ.png)

i want to change like this

```
{
  "Students":
  [
     [1, 2, "tom", true]
  ],
  "OtherOne":[true, 1, "test"]
}
```

thank you for read @__@

Comment: You want to return an object containing a property named `Students` which is an array of something right? Can you describe more what you want in Students and OtherOne, I don't understand `[1, 2, "tom", true]` and `[true, 1, "test"]`:  arrays can only contains a single type of data.

Comment: why arrays can only contains a single type of data? swagger did not support many data type? boolean, string, integer, else...

Comment: A Swagger array only support one type of data (you define it with `items` like in your example). Can you explain what is `[1, 2, "tom", true]`? So I can propose you a solution.

Comment: [1, 2, "tom", true] just example for understand. meaningless. another example is here.`{
  "mobliePhone": [
    "iPhone",
    "LG-G5",
    "Galaxy S7"
  ],
  "moblieOS": [
    "iOS",
    "Android",
    "Chrome OS"
  ],
  "isInterest": [
    true,
    "yes",
    false
  ],
  "favoriteCompany": "Apple"
}` can you convert this response to swagger spec yaml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger-Editor model array with distinct types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41904148/113116)