# Swagger-Editor model array with distinct types

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have a return type which is an array of two elements.  The first element is an integer and the second element is an array of dictionary with keys of `sql_ident` and `name`.  The `sql_ident` value is an integer and the `name` value is a string.

I can't figure out how to model this in my response object.  So it'd be like:

```json
[
   12,
   [
      {
        "sql_ident" : 17,
        "name" : "Billy Bob"
      },
      {
        "sql_ident" : 935,
        "name" : "Tina Turner"
      } 
   ]
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create different element types within Swagger 2.0 editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690802/how-to-create-different-element-types-within-swagger-2-0-editor)

Answer (score 0):

In OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, array items must be of the same type, so there is no way to precisely model your response. The most you can do is to use a [typeless schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328994/113116) for `items`, which means the items can be anything - numbers, objects, strings, etc. - but you can't specify the exact types for items.

```yaml
definitions:
  MyResponse:
    type: array
    items: {}
```

In OpenAPI 3.0, multi-type arrays can be described using `oneOf` and `anyOf`:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    MyResponse:
      type: array
      items:
        oneOf:
          - type: integer
          - type: array
            items:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/MyDictionary"

    MyDictionary:
      type: object
      properties:
        sql_ident:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
```