# Is it possible to specify an API response array (used as an ordered pair) in Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have a need to document an API via Swagger.
The api response has 2 element arrays like this:

[[RFC3339 timestamp, float64 value], ...]

I am not sure how to define the ordered pair (which we use a 2 element array for). That is "[RFC3339 timestamp, float64 value]"

Does anyone have any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger-Editor model array with distinct types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41904148/113116)

Comment: See my answer in the linked question. Multi-type arrays (such as timestamp + float64) are not supported in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, but will be supported in the upcoming 3.0.