# Specifying multiple types for additionalProperties through Swagger/OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am looking to represent the following JSON Object in OpenAPI:

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 4,
  ...
}
```

The number of properties and the property names are not fully predetermined, so I look to use additionalProperties. However, I'm not too certain how it would be represented through OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0. I tried this:

```
Person:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    type:
      - int
      - string
```

or the JSON equivalent:

```
{
  "Person": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
      "type": ["int", "string"]
    }
  }
}
```

but that didn't quite work. Is there any way to keep the structure of the JSON Object I want to represent, for specifically strings and integers, and not arbitrary object types?

Comment: @Helen It is not quite arbitrary; I know that it will be either a string or an int, but not booleans or nulls or other objects.

Comment: Related: [Swagger-Editor model array with distinct types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41904148/113116)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### OpenAPI 3.1

In OpenAPI 3.1, the `type` keyword can take a list of types:

```yaml
Person:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    type: [string, integer]
```

### OpenAPI 3.x

OpenAPI 3.0+ supports `oneOf` so you can use:

```yaml
Person:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    oneOf:
      - type: string
      - type: integer
```

### OpenAPI 2.0

OpenAPI 2.0 does not support multi-type values. The most you can do is use the [typeless schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328994/113116), which means the additional properties can be anything - strings, numbers, booleans, and so on - but you can't specify the exact types.

```yaml
Person:
  type: object
  additionalProperties: {}
```

This is equivalent to:

```yaml
Person:
  type: object
```