# How to handle multiple data types for a single field in Swagger 2.0?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

Facing difficulty in construct a swagger YAML for an API with multiple types available for a single field. Swagger 2.0 doesn't support oneOf, anyOf, not in schema specification.

Example:

```
filter:{
        descr:"Filter Options",
        oneOf:[ 
        {
            type:"object"
        },
        {
            type:"array",
            items:{
                type: "string"
            }
        }
        ]
  }
```

This Filter field expects an object or array. Swagger 2.0 is used to validate the request and allow the valid one.

```
filter: 
 descr: "user defined attribute filter"
 jsonstr: true
 oneOf: 
  - 
   type: object
  - 
   type: array
   items: 
    type: string
```

This YAML structure is completely possible in Swagger 3.0 (Open API Specification).

Whether this kind of YAML is possible in Swagger 2.0 ? or any other alternative approach available to perform this in Swagger 2.0

Thanks to all suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create different element types within Swagger 2.0 editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690802/how-to-create-different-element-types-within-swagger-2-0-editor), [Specifying multiple types for additionalProperties through Swagger/OpenAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46472543/113116)

Comment: Thanks! for this post and it clarify my doubt in using multiple data types. Will try to upgrade OAS 3.0 and start using this.